# Avoid Multiple Instances of Service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, singleton

I have done some research on the net, and I have figured out that the problem I am facing is that multiple instances of service are being created, and I want to avoid that. Can some one please look at my code and spot the change I need to make.

Second service that uses the primary service that is being duplicated.

```
export class SecondaryService {
    constructor(private primarySvc: IPrimaryService){
        this.primarySvc.someSubject.subscribe(() => {});
    }
}
```

Primary Service (the one that is being duplicated)

```
export class PrimaryService {
    someSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    constructor(){}
}
```

Primary Service Provider

```
@Injectable()
export class PrimaryServiceProvider extends PrimaryService {
     constructor(){
          super();
     }
}
```

Secondary Service Provider

```
@Injectable()
export class SecondaryServiceProvider extends SecondaryService {
    constructor(private PrimaryProvider: PrimaryServiceProvider){
        super(PrimaryProvider);
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
     declaration: [SecondaryComponent],
     exports: [SecondaryComponent],
     imports: [BrowserModule],
     providers: [SecondaryServiceProvider, PrimaryServiceProvider ]
 })
 export class SearchModule{}
```

Now I am trying to use the component I made in a local environment which looks something like this:

app.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
     declaration: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
     imports: [SearchModule, BrowserModule],
     providers: [PrimaryServiceProvider, SecondaryServiceProvider],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule{}
```

home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor( primarySvc: PrimaryServiceProvider, 
        secondarySvc: SecondaryServiceProvider) {
        this.primarySvc.someSubject.next(false);
    }
}
```

Now I know for sure the Primary Service has two instances since `someSubject` is not in sync, and the subscribe in SecondarySvc is not fetching any values from home.component.ts

Please tell me where do i need to make the changes

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you run the app on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Remove providers from SearchModule

Comment: @DiakoAmir unfortunately i dont know how to make a local environment in stackblitz.com, I feel without which I wouldn't be able to re-create the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own Question:

The services were duplicated due to incorrect file path while importing. Windows lets you use case-insensitive file paths, which may create multiple instances for every time the module is used.

Comment: For me it was my auto import on Webstorm with Lerna. It caused a relative path to create when it shouldn't have.

Comment: seems incredibly fragile design. Make one tiny change in the path, such as using a relative path instead of absolute, and suddenly you have a second instance of a service.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are overengineering using the `PrimaryServiceProvider` and `SecondaryServiceProvider` services.

To create a singleton service just set `providedIn: 'root'` option in the `Injectable` decorator, like this:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SecondaryService {}
```

At last, be sure to not register a singleton service at any `providers` array.

Check out the official documentation about this [here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Comment: Thanks for the response @yasser, this is a part of a huge project, so i cant remove any of the two services.. Secondly, it is the PrimaryService that is being duplicated not the SecondaryService